# "estimate_contrasts" in the R package "modelbased" change the order of the levels of factors

Tags: r, posthoc

I am using the new package "modelbased" in the "easystats" collection of packages to implement posthoc comparisons analysis on my linear model using the function "estimate_constrasts". This function output is changing the order of the factor levels to an alphabetic order. See the example below with the iris data.

```
data(iris)
# changing the order of the levels of the factor "Species" to NOT be in alphabetic order
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, levels =c("virginica", "versicolor","setosa")) 
levels(iris$Species) # now the level order is "virginica"  "versicolor" "setosa"    
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris) 
library(easystats)
estimate_contrasts(model, "Species",method="trt.vs.ctrl")
```

| Level1 | Level2 | Difference | 95% CI | SE | t(147) | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| setosa | virginica | -1.58 | [-1.82, -1.35] | 0.10 | -15.37 | < .001 |
| versicolor | virginica | -0.65 | [-0.89, -0.42] | 0.10 | -6.33 | < .001 |

Instead of showing the normal order of levels as in the package emmeans

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model, specs = trt.vs.ctrl ~ Species)$contrasts
```

| contrast | estimate | SE | df | t.ratio | p.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| versicolor - virginica | -0.652 | 0.103 | 147 | -6.333 | <.0001 |
| setosa - virginica | -1.582 | 0.103 | 147 | -15.366 | <.0001 |

How can I tell estimate_contrasts to use the order of the levels in my data?

Comment: In your second output example both rows have the same values.

Comment: I have changed it to the correct value. Thank you @Ric

Answer (score 2):

From the output of the first case i think you can reorder the table based on the levels of iris$Species (except the base level).

```
result <- estimate_contrasts(model, "Species",method="trt.vs.ctrl")
result[match(levels(iris$Species)[-1], result$Level1), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as aiming to show the contrast from different directions.

Reading `contrast_means`'s and `emmeans`'s help files, specifying `method` argument worked for me!
https://rdrr.io/cran/emmeans/man/contrast.html

```
estimate_contrasts(model, "Species",method="revpairwise")
```